# Python beginner unable to import a module

Tags: python

I am very new to python, and I try to import a module, and I am unable to.

**NOTE** I am also using some external dependencies, which I will not include them in the question. I have no problem with imports inside the `hl7_utils.py`

The python verison is 3.7

here is my project structure:

```
-src:
    final_client.py
    hl7_utils.py
    __init__.py
```

Here is the **hl7_utils** content:

```
from hl7apy.core import Message

from sepsis_1.sepsis_one import SepsisOne


def create_sepsis_message(key, value):
    print('removed contents for brevity')


def generate_hl7_analysis_for_patient():
    print('removed contents for brevity')
```

And here is my **final_client.py**:

```
from hl7_utils import generate_hl7_analysis_for_patient

generate_hl7_analysis_for_patient()
```

The **__init__.py** is empty

Why do I get the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hl7_utils' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hl7apy'

if you run **python3 final_client.py**

remove these:

```
from hl7apy.core import Message

from sepsis_1.sepsis_one import SepsisOne
```

and you be able to run without error:

```
$ python3 final_client.py 
removed contents for brevity
```

Comment: but I need that imports because they are used in my functions (I have removed the logic here in the question)

Comment: These are external dependencies, installed using pip

Comment: So you can install it, I resolved one of problems. You said that  No module named 'hl7_utils'. But it is yours

Comment: how do you run python?

Comment: from terminal python3 run

Comment: which file?
python3 final_client.py;
python3 hl7_utils.py;
or how?